# Typescript can't infer type of property using conditionals

Tags: typescript, types

I wanted to create a function which only allows properties which are string arrays, this is what I thought would work

```ts
export function cloneDocsOnProperty<T extends Object> (clonedObject: T, property: {[k in keyof T]?: T[k] extends string[]? k: never}[keyof T]) {
    const values = clonedObject[property]
    for (const value of values) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The function signature "works", i.e, the auto-completion shows properties which are string arrays but if I try to iterate through the property it says

```
Type 'T[{ [k in keyof T]?: T[k] extends string[] ? k : never; }[keyof T]]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: [ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAEAzArgOwMbwJbXYpgDb6gAi0mAzgPLoAKs0koCAngDwAqiE8o6ACZVENAEYArUNgB8iABTFSg8VOwAuRFwA0iSExbtNAbwDaAa0Q4C50G2jItAXQD8mrhae9w-ISKrwsNYA5qauiOaa6KAAbqwAvhZ2Ds4AlIjGwIjZhPgBiDEAhkSooCIAvIQk0SqS0vCm+sys8GxOWTnIcAqYeUhFJaCIKQOlVOmZOVO56FTQRKAAdCTB8qOgqR3Z8cA7wL2zSF3QiJWTOWKFsJoAROBsAF432lso0NAAQleapjeFYphnog7o8bk4XlNBIUHj8AIy6P4AsFTXYgJTRCjUOiMZrseTHBFiG6bIA), it gives me a different error than what I got locally (using TS 4.5.5)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQgaD.png)

What I meant was that the compiler doesn't understand that the property is a string[] (that's why we get the error in the for..of), but the compiler gives another error if you pass in any property except fooBar, which I thought was proof that the type signature wasn't completely insane.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"The function signature "works", i.e, the auto-completion shows properties which are string arrays but if I try to iterate through the property..."* Please show that code (including the call to the function) in the question. (Ideally, both in the question and with the other code above it on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)). The code you currently have in the question has an error prior to the `for-of`: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wR5yQW)

Comment: I can replicate the error if I change your types around [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzQGx2ABEI0BnAeRQAUoIxhYBPAHgBU5QZgUATcnEoAjAFbAMAPgAUAWABQcJXkIpgfEeIwAuOAG8A2gGs4mXEeDMICOOwC6Afl3tjdriB79B5GFDMBzA0c4I101ADcmAF8AGgVlODB6RhZdCysbdgUASn145TQcHzhwgEN8JGBBAF4VIg0xCRgDJIYmGGY7fKUEaDhpQpRisorgOGsS8sryXL1uhLgAekW4ADp1+aiFKKA) but the autocomplete shows all the property names. So please do update the question with your actual code giving the behavior described.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I really didn't expect a comment so quickly. I meant something [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmA8AcHsCcBcAEAzArgOwMbwJbXYpgDb6gAi0mAzgPLoAKs0koCAngDwAqiE8o6ACZVENAEYArUNgB8iABTFSg8VOwAuRFwA0iSExbtNAbwDaAa0Q4C50G2jItAXQD8mrhae9w-ISKrwsNYA5qauiOaa6KAAbqwAvhZ2Ds4AlIjGwIjZhPgBiDEAhkSooCIAvIQk0SqS0vCm+sys8GxOWTnIcAqYeUhFJaCIKQOlVOmZOVO56FTQRKAAdCTB8qOgqR3Z8cA7wL2zSF3QiJWTOWKFsJoAROBsAF432lso0NAAQleapjeFYphnog7o8bk4XlNBIUHj8AIy6P4AsFTXYgJTRCjUOiMZrseTHBFiG6bIA). If you try passing the property names, fooBar gets autocompleted in but the others don't

Comment: The compiler complains if you pass in any property except fooBar. Regardless, is there a flaw in my reasoning (i.e is there an example of parameters where clonedObject[property] is not a string[]) or is it a typescript limitation

Comment: I got a different error locally (ts 4.5.5) which I attached to the OP

Comment: For me, this is one of those times when I'll give up and throw a type assertion at it [like this](https://tsplay.dev/N54MPw) (note I got rid of the `undefined` offered value for the function argument via `Exclude`; another way is to add a conditional branch using `K extends string`). I don't know why TypeScript can't see that in the function, `clonedObject[property]` is `string[]`, but it definitely is. I avoid type assertions like crazy, but in a small function like this where I've done all I can otherwise, I'm okay with them. I hope you find a better way though.